# Creating a list of Quiz questions that have randomized order?

Tags: views, quiz

I'm using the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module and created a view (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) which lists all of the questions of the current Quiz being accessed, and whether each question has been completed.

The only issue is the sorting of these questions. When the quiz has the question order set to random the list does not update to reflect this change, since the questions are being ordered by weight.

This is a problem because a user may have just completed the first question but by weight it may be question 6, which is visually confusing. Therefore how can one create a list of the questions that reflect the randomized ordering of the Quiz?

I looked at the "Quiz: Randomization" field but I am not quite sure how to use this. It causes an SQL error if I try to enable it.

Comment: Quiz questions are nodes? Have you tried to select **Global: Random** in the view's **Sort Criteria**?

Comment: Sure I have tried this; but how can I set the questions to have the same random order as that of the random order of the Quiz module? The Quiz module has an option to randomize the question order, but I am not sure how to replicate this sort order in Views.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with the Quiz module. If I find some time I'll try to dive into this.